# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer == integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using these statements in a postgres function.

```
Select count(*) into V_check
from employee
where employee_name like 'Raj%';

if V_check == 0
then
     update exception set exception_found = 'Raj';
end if;
```

I get this error  :

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == integer
> LINE 1: SELECT V_check == 0
> ```

Comment: What is `==`? How does it compare to `=`?

Comment: Equality is `=`, not `==`. This is SQL, not C/C++/Java

Answer (score 17):

You should use `=` instead of `==`.

Here is a list of the different comparison operators that you can use:

```
Operator    Description
=   Equal
<>  Not equal. Note: In some versions of SQL this operator may be written as !=
>   Greater than
<   Less than
>=  Greater than or equal
<=  Less than or equal
BETWEEN Between an inclusive range
LIKE    Search for a pattern
IN  To specify multiple possible values for a column
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, the comparison operator for equality is `=` not `==`.  However, you should write the condition as:

```
if not exists (select 1 from employee where employee_name like 'Raj%')
then
     update exception
         set exception_found = 'Raj';
end if;
```

This saves you a declaration.  Also, `not exists` is faster than `count(*)` -- because `not exists` can stop at the first matching row.

Or dispense with the conditional entirely:

```
update exception 
    set exception_found = 'Raj'
    where not exists (select 1 from employee where employee_name like 'Raj%');
```